# Cant seem to get this "count" to work. Every time I push the button both led and light turn on regardless of code

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm very new to coding as a whole. And have spend ages trying to get this to work but it all looks like it should work fine too me. The plan is to have ledPin light up when the button is pressed and lightPin light up every 8 presses.

This is some engineering college work. As you can tell there's a reason I didn't go with computer science!

```
const int buttonPin = 2; // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int lightPin = 3
const int ledPin = 13; // the number of the LED pin
int count = 0; // Count the button presses

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup()
{
// initialize the LED pin as an output:
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
// initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
// read the state of the pushbutton value:
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

// check if the pushbutton is pressed.
// if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
    if (buttonState == HIGH)
    {
// turn LED on:   
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        count++; // add 1 to the count
        if (count >= 8)
        {
            digitalWrite(lightPin, HIGH);
            delay(1000)
            digitalWrite(lightPin, LOW);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
// turn LED off:
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    }
}
```

The ledPin should light up with each button press. And every 8 presses the lightPin should light up. But currently both light up with each button press and their duration seems to be tied to the delay.

Comment: maybe reading this will help you with the problem you're having https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce

Comment: You need to read about switch debouncing in software. Also, `lightPin` isn't initialized to an output in your code. That seems to be OK because it is still acting as one but you should do it to ensure that it actually is. It is also a good idea to initialize output to a known state (either high or low depending on the desired logic).

Comment: Also, just want to clear the misconception that this is computer science. It's not at all. This is elementary level embedded systems.